# I want to use $index of ng-repeat in same tag line

Tags: angularjs

I want to use $index of ng-repeat in same tag line

```
<uib-tabset active="activeameneties" justified="true" class="resp-tabs-list hor_1 classforfont">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="amenity in prop.all_amenities" class="ami_tabs" index=" " heading="{{amenity.amenity}}" index="{{amenity.id}}"> 
        <div class="resp-tabs-container hor_1" >
            <div class="extMar">
                <br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-6  col-xs-12" ng-repeat="sub_amenity in amenity.subAmenities">
                        <div class="prop-checkbox">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-inline">
                                <input id="Smoking-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="Smoking-1" type="checkbox" value={{sub_amenity.id}}>
                                <label for="Smoking-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">{{sub_amenity.amenity}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: can you please more elaborate your question with explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with `{{$index}}` or `$index` directly; depending on the kind of attribute to which you're providing this value.

Have a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/PGyrBy) for example.